# How to retain calculated values between rows when calculating running totals?

Tags: sas

I have a tricky question about conditional sum in SAS. Actually, it is very complicated for me and therefore, I cannot explain it by words. Therefore I want to show an example:

```
 A      B
 5      3
 7      2
 8      6
 6      4
 9      5
 8      2
 3      1
 4      3
```

As you can see, I have a datasheet that has two columns. First of all, I calculated the conditional cumulative sum of column A ( I can do it by myself-So no need help for that step):

```
 A      B    CA
 5      3    5
 7      2    12
 8      6    18    
 6      4    8     ((12+8)-18)+6
 9      5    17   
 8      2    18
 3      1    10    (((17+8)-18)+3
 4      3    14
```

So my condition value is 18. If the cumulative more than 18, then it equal 18 and next value if sum of the first value after 18 and exceeds amount over 18. ( As I said I can do it by myself )
So the tricky part is I have to calculate the cumulative sum of column B according to column A:

```
 A      B    CA    CB
 5      3    5     3
 7      2    12    5
 8      6    18    9.5 (5+(6*((18-12)/8)))
 6      4    8     5.5 ((5+6)-9.5)+4
 9      5    17    10.5 (5.5+5)
 8      2    18    10.75 (10.5+(2*((18-7)/8)))
 3      1    10    2.75 ((10.5+2)-10.75)+1
 4      3    14    5.75 (2.75+3)
```

As you can see from example the cumulative sum of column B is very specific. When column CA is equal to our condition value (18), then we calculate the proportion of the last value for getting our condition value (18) and then use this proportion for computing cumulative sum of column B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like when the sum of A reaches 18 or more you want to split the values of A and B between the current and the next record.  One way is to remember the left over values for A and B and carry them forward in your new cumulative variables. Just make sure to output the observation before resetting those variables.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  ca+a;
  cb+b;
  if ca >= 18 then do;
    extra_a=ca - 18;
    extra_b=b - b*((a - extra_a)/a) ;
    ca=18;
    cb=cb-extra_b ;
  end;
  output;
  if ca=18 then do;
    ca=extra_a;
    cb=extra_b;
  end;
  drop extra_a extra_b ;
run;
```